# How to use the IN operator in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to filter on records where clientAppUsed are either 'Exchange ActiveSync' or 'Exchange Web Services'.

I'm able to do it this way:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=clientAppUsed eq 'Exchange ActiveSync' or clientAppUsed eq 'Exchange Web Services'
```

But I want to use the **in** operator.

According to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#examples-using-the-filter-query-operator

My query should look like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=clientAppUsed in ('Exchange ActiveSync', 'Exchange Web Services')
```

But it doen't work.

```
UnknownError: Please try again after some time.
```

I have waited and tried again, with the same result.

Does anyone know how to use the in operator correctly or have a different way of getting the same result without the query getting very long?

Answer (score 0):

The In operator might be used if only few scenarios as mentioned in the [DOC](https://users?$filter=department%20in%20(%27Retail%27,%20%27Sales%27),)

Can you please check if this is happening for your query only or is the "In" operator not working for any query.

Try this One:

```html
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=department in ('Retail', 'Sales')
```